# For loop acting on vector of integers is behaving strangely

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> normalize(std::vector<int> a) {
    for (int j = a.size() - 1; j > 0; --j) {
        while (a[j] > 9) {
            a[j] = a[j] - 10;
            std::cout << '!'; //Just to test if the loop is executed (the correct # of times)
            ++a[j - 1];
        }
    }
// checks that the last digit isnt too large, makes new digit otherwise
    if (a[0] > 9) {
        a.insert(a.begin(), 0);
        while (a[1] > 9) {
            a[1] -= 10;
            ++a[0];
        }
    }

    return a;
}
// for debugging convenience
void printVector(std::vector<int> a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(1); a.push_back(2); a.push_back(33);
    normalize(a);
    printVector(a);

    return 0;
}
```

This program represents large integers as lists of digits, The normalize function would change {1,2,33} to {1,5,3}, representing 153, for instance. I'm new to C++ so I'm not using classes and I'm not using any big integer headers that would have this all much better implemented.

Returns: !!!1 2 33
as though the vector has not been changed. But then how would the "std::cout '!'" line print the correct number of times, or even the while loop terminate at all?

Comment: *I'm new to C++* -- You should learn the other tools of the trade, more succinctly, the debugger.  Then you can step through your program and see where it goes awry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function

```
std::vector<int> normalize(std::vector<int> a)
```

you are passing `a` by value, so it won't be modified once the function exits. To make it work, you should use your current implementation as

```
auto result = normalize(a); // now we get the result
printVector(result); // and display it
```

To avoid making an un-necessary copy, you should pass the agument by const reference:

```
std::vector<int> normalize(std::vector<int> const& a)
```

If you want to modify the parameter that's passed to your function, you should pass by reference:

```
std::vector<int> normalize(std::vector<int>& a) // now we can modify a
```

However, it's a good idea to implement functions as black boxes without side effects (if possible), as it will make testing and multi-threading much easier, so I'd suggest passing by const reference then returning the result.

Comment: The last paragraph doesn't make much sense, at least in this case. Modifying the vector in-place versus returning the modified version has no impact whatsoever on testing or multithreading - what you don't want there are modifications to the *global* state. If a function is best written to work in place go for it, as it avoids unnecessary copies and you can always get the copying behavior trivially (construct a copy outside and call the function over the copy).

Comment: @MatteoItalia I was thinking of a situation where 2 threads invoke the function on the same input parameter. I agree that in super-critical performance apps one should squeeze out everything out of the language, but I am a bit biased towards functional-programming style of coding, probably due to my math-oriented style of thinking.

Comment: in that case they'll just have to make a local copy before calling the function. Functional programming is nice, but is best done in a language that supports it efficiently. In functional languages lists are returned all the time because passing them around is cheap (you are actually passing them by reference), in C++ it's not. Sure, there's move semantics, copy elision and whatnot, but you always have to think three times before being sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your function uses pass-by-value. This means that the call `normalize(a);` does not modify `a`, it modifies a copy of `a`.

To fix this there are two ways:

1. Make the call `a = normalize(a);`
2. Make the function have `void` return type, and use pass-by-reference (put a `&` in the function prototype before the parameter name).

The first way is more natural but unfortunately has performance problems for large vectors, so most people would prefer the second way

NB. You currently don't handle the possibility of `a[0] > 9` after the insert and adjustment;  and it would be simpler to store the least-significant digit first, then you can append instead of inserting at the front, and you wouldn't need to divide your algorithm up into the two parts.

Comment: There is a `return`, but the code was poorly indented, I've just re-formatted it.